# NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 64

Tags: ios, nsxmlparsererrordomain

I have to call xml parsing I am receiving this error "NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 64", if I will parse dynamically I will get this error. statically parsing on that same xml I get my attribute values.

If i will try another one server different request,url and response it will working properly the xml parsing and i am getting attribute values.

Comment: meaning of error 64 is given in iOS documentation. Please read it.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link==>http://brandontreb.com/wordpress-for-iphoneipad-nsxmlparsererrordomain-error-64-resolved

*After scouring the internet, I found that this could be the result of a few issues.

1) Special characters in a post body that are not supported by NSXMLParser

2) Special characters in a comment

3) Invalid post or comment RSS

4) An error in a theme/plugin file

For me, this turned out to be an issue with the comments RSS feed. I loaded it up in the browser and long behold, even the browser threw an error. But what could be causing this? Turns out, I had left a space in a plugin that I created. This caused a space to be output at the beginning of the comments XML, causing it to error. Notice the space between ?> and

After removing the space from this plugin, I loaded up WordPress for iPhone and it added my blog without a problem.

So, the take away from this is don’t output spaces when you create a plugin.*

Hope this helps you...:-)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was only the blank line at the beginning of the file that was causing the issue. Error code 64 is for misplaced XML declaration as you can see in the documentation:

```
NSXMLParserMisplacedXMLDeclarationError = 64,
Misplaced XML declaration.
```